# How to change to rootLayer of the playn AndroidPlatform?

Tags: android, playn

All the layers of my game are scaled and positioned for a rootLayer with a ratio **2:1**.

For example, under the java version I did that :

```
Config config = new Config();
config.width = 800;
config.height = 400;
JavaPlatform platform = JavaPlatform.register(config);
```

For Android I'd like to change the rootLayer to have the max width possible, and the height = width / 2.

For a resolution of 800x480 (like the **Google Nexus S**), the rootLayer would be in 800x400, and positioned at (0, 40).

Is it possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to do it. If playn developpers pass through here they may tell me if that's the best way to do it.

I override the **setContentView** method of the GameActivity. In the parent, the method append the GameViewGL to the main layout. So, I copied the code and modified it to add my size and position specifications :

```
  @Override
  protected void setContentView(GameViewGL view) {
    BitmapDrawable bmp = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), "");
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(bmp);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    layout.addView(view);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    Point size = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
    if (size.y > size.x) {
        params.width = size.y;
        params.height = size.y / 2;
        layout.setY((size.x - size.y / 2) / 2);
    } else {
        params.width = size.x;
        params.height = size.x / 2;
        layout.setY((size.y - size.x / 2) / 2);
    }
    getWindow().setContentView(layout, params);
  }
```